# Proton creation

Tags: antimatter, protons

My question is simple:  if proton antiproton pairs can be created in the laboratory (given certain energies) then they should also be able to be created in the universe at any time, not only during the Big Bang.

So, for example, a quasar could be a giant proton factory, or an accretion disc at the center of a galaxy could have energies much higher than any laboratory and the relativistic jets which are vertical to the disc could contain newly created protons, after the proton antiproton asymmetry is accounted for.

Comment: Why wouldn't the protons immediately annihilate with the antiprotons?

Comment: Are you asking whether your statements are true? It isn't completely clear...

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is how proton cosmic rays are produced... quasars, supernovae, gamma rays bursts... also anti proton cosmic rays originate from proton anti proton creation in proton cosmic ray collision with nuclei in interstellar medium (otherwise anti protons cannot leave the vicinity of a matter dominated (as opposed to anti-matter) source)